# How to shorten the Join layers in Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, linq, join

Whenever you add join a new layer is added and this is difficult to work especially in the where dynamic clause
How can I summarize each join with one word
I put a query that shows the queries I mean
I use here several join and each Gwen adds me t
Every field I want to add or query must add a long string of t
I want to write the name you named for the join directly

```
context.Trips
    .GroupJoin(context.Entities, trips => trips.BeneficiaryEntitiesId, beneficiarys => beneficiarys.Id,
        (trips, tripsEntities) => new { trips, tripsEntities })
    .SelectMany(t => t.tripsEntities.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (t, beneficiarys) => new { t, beneficiarys })
    .GroupJoin(context.Items, t => t.t.trips.ItemId, items => items.Id,
        (t, tripsItems) => new { t, tripsItems })
    .SelectMany(t => t.tripsItems.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (t, items) => new { t, items })
    .Join(context.Entities, t => t.t.t.t.trips.CarrierEntitiesId,
        carriers => carriers.Id,
        (t, carriers) => new { t, carriers })
    .Join(context.Vehicl, t => t.t.t.t.t.trips.VehiclId,
        vehicls => vehicls.Id,
        (t, vehicls) => new { t, vehicls })
    .Join(context.DefineLists, t => t.vehicls.VehiclType,
        vehiclsType => vehiclsType.Id,
        (t, vehiclsType) => new { t, vehiclsType })
    .Join(context.Drivers, t => t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.EntryDriverId,
         endrivers => endrivers.Id,
        (t, endrivers) => new { t, endrivers })
    .GroupJoin(context.Drivers, t => t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.OutputDriverId,
        oudrivers => oudrivers.Id,
        (t, oudrivers) => new { t, oudrivers })
    .SelectMany(t => t.oudrivers.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (t, oudrivers) => new { t, oudrivers })
    .Where(@$"(t.t.t.vehiclsType.ListType==1 {SDateWhere}{EDateWhere})
                      {SubWhere}{MainWhere}", StartDate, ed)
    .Select(s => new
    {
        s.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.Id,
        TripsFullNo = $"{s.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.TripsFullNo}   {s.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.TripsNo}",
        OperationTtype =
            s.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.Loading
                ? operationTtypes[s.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.trips.OperationTtype ?? 0]
                : $"{Language.ListOperateTransfer} {Language.ListEmpt}",
        Vehicl = $"{s.t.t.t.t.vehicls.LicensePlate}/{s.t.t.t.vehiclsType.ListItem}",
        CarrierEntities = s.t.t.t.t.t.carriers.EntitieName,
        BeneficiaryEntities = s.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.t.beneficiarys!.EntitieName,
        Item = s.t.t.t.t.t.t.items!.NoName,
        Driver = $"{s.t.t.endrivers.DriverLicense}/{s.t.t.endrivers.DriverName}"
    }).OrderByDescending(o=>o.Id)
```

Comment: I can only propose to use Query syntax and do not use Dynamic Linq at all. For which purpose it is introduced in your project?

Comment: Please correct the errors in your question, it makes some parts very difficult to understand. For your question, there is no reason you couldn't surface the parts you use later in the query to the top level so they are always only one level deep. That transforms depth for width in your query.

Comment: For example, what does "and each Gwen adds me t Every field I want" try to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of transforming depth into width as you create many joins. Note that using EF/EF Core properly can make nested joins unnecessary and much easier to work with.

```
var test = db.GroupJoin(context.Entities,
                 trips => trips.BeneficiaryEntitiesId, beneficiarys => beneficiarys.Id,
                (trips, tripEntities) => new { trips, tripEntities })
            .SelectMany(
                 tb => tb.tripEntities.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (tb, beneficiaries) => new { tb.trips, beneficiaries })
            .GroupJoin(context.Items,
                 tb => tb.trips.ItemId, items => items.Id,
                (tb, tripsItems) => new { tb.trips, tb.beneficiaries, tripsItems })
            .SelectMany(
                 tbi => tbi.tripsItems.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (tbi, items) => new { tbi.trips, tbi.beneficiaries, items })
            .Join(context.Entities,
                 tbi => tbi.trips.CarrierEntitiesId, carriers => carriers.Id,
                (tbi, carriers) => new { tbi.trips, tbi.beneficiaries, tbi.items, carriers })
            .Join(context.Vehicl,
                 tbic => tbic.trips.VehiclId, vehicls => vehicls.Id,
                (tbic, vehicls) => new { tbic.trips, tbic.beneficiaries, tbic.items, tbic.carriers, vehicls })
            .Join(context.DefineLists,
                 tbicv => tbicv.vehicls.VehiclType, vehiclsType => vehiclsType.Id,
                (tbicv, vehiclsType) => new { tbicv.trips, tbicv.beneficiaries, tbicv.items, tbicv.carriers, tbicv.vehicls, vehiclsType })
            .Join(context.Drivers,
                 tbicvv => tbicvv.trips.EntryDriverId, endrivers => endrivers.Id,
                (tbicvv, endrivers) => new { tbicvv.trips, tbicvv.beneficiaries, tbicvv.items, tbicvv.carriers, tbicvv.vehicls, tbicvv.vehiclsType, endrivers })
            .GroupJoin(context.Drivers,
                 tbicvve => tbicvve.trips.OutputDriverId, oudrivers => oudrivers.Id,
                (tbicvve, oudrivers) => new { tbicvve.trips, tbicvve.beneficiaries, tbicvve.items, tbicvve.carriers, tbicvve.vehicls, tbicvve.vehiclsType, tbicvve.endrivers, oudrivers })
            .SelectMany(
                 tbicvveo => tbicvveo.oudrivers.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (tbicvveo, oudrivers) => new { tbicvveo.trips, tbicvveo.beneficiaries, tbicvveo.items, tbicvveo.carriers, tbicvveo.vehicls, tbicvveo.vehiclsType, tbicvveo.endrivers, oudrivers })
            .Where(@$"(trips.vehiclsType.ListType==1 {SDateWhere}{EDateWhere}) {SubWhere}{MainWhere}", StartDate, ed)
            .Select(tbcvvo => new {
                tbcvvo.trips.Id,
                TripsFullNo = $"{tbcvvo.trips.TripsFullNo}   {tbcvvo.trips.TripsNo}",
                OperationTtype =
                    tbcvvo.trips.Loading
                        ? operationTtypes[tbcvvo.trips.OperationTtype ?? 0]
                        : $"{Language.ListOperateTransfer} {Language.ListEmpt}",
                Vehicl = $"{tbcvvo.vehicls.LicensePlate}/{tbcvvo.vehiclsType.ListItem}",
                CarrierEntities = tbcvvo.carriers.EntitieName,
                BeneficiaryEntities = tbcvvo.beneficiaries!.EntitieName,
                Item = tbcvvo.items!.NoName,
                Driver = $"{tbcvvo.endrivers.DriverLicense}/{tbcvvo.endrivers.DriverName}"
            })
            .OrderByDescending(o=>o.Id)
```

Comment: Thank you, you solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

By creating an extension method to represent `LeftJoin`, which requires using a known class for the results, you can combine the `GroupJoin` and `SelectMany` operations with some minor naming issues as well.

Given:

```
public class AnswerClass<TOuter, TInner> {
    public TOuter O;
    public TInner I;
}

public static class IQueryableExt {
    public static IQueryable<AnswerClass<TOuter, TInner>> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
        IQueryable<TInner> inner, Expression<Func<TOuter,TKey>> outerKeyFn, Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeyFn)
        => outer.GroupJoin(inner, outerKeyFn, innerKeyFn, (outer, inners) => new { outer, inners })
                .SelectMany(oi => oi.inners.DefaultIfEmpty(), (oi, i) => new AnswerClass<TOuter, TInner> { O = oi.outer, I = i });
}

var test = db.LeftJoin(context.Entities, trips => trips.BeneficiaryEntitiesId, beneficiaries => beneficiaries.Id)
            .LeftJoin(context.Items, oi => oi.O.ItemId, items => items.Id)
            .Join(context.Entities,
                 ooi => ooi.O.O.CarrierEntitiesId, carriers => carriers.Id,
                (ooi, carriers) => new { trips = ooi.O.O, beneficiary = ooi.O.I, items = ooi.I, carriers })
            .Join(context.Vehicl,
                 tbic => tbic.trips.VehiclId, vehicls => vehicls.Id,
                (tbic, vehicls) => new { tbic.trips, tbic.beneficiary, tbic.items, tbic.carriers, vehicls })
            .Join(context.DefineLists,
                 tbicv => tbicv.vehicls.VehiclType, vehiclsType => vehiclsType.Id,
                (tbicv, vehiclsType) => new { tbicv.trips, tbicv.beneficiary, tbicv.items, tbicv.carriers, tbicv.vehicls, vehiclsType })
            .Join(context.Drivers,
                 tbicvv => tbicvv.trips.EntryDriverId, endrivers => endrivers.Id,
                (tbicvv, endrivers) => new { tbicvv.trips, tbicvv.beneficiary, tbicvv.items, tbicvv.carriers, tbicvv.vehicls, tbicvv.vehiclsType, endrivers })
            .LeftJoin(context.Drivers, tbicvve => tbicvve.trips.OutputDriverId, oudrivers => oudrivers.Id)
            // Remap LeftJoin result to something with better naming
            .Select(oi => new { oi.O.trips, oi.O.beneficiary, oi.O.items, oi.O.carriers, oi.O.vehicls, oi.O.vehiclsType, oi.O.endrivers, ouDrivers = oi.I })
            //.Where(@$"(trips.vehiclsType.ListType==1 {SDateWhere}{EDateWhere}) {SubWhere}{MainWhere}", StartDate, ed)
            .Select(tbcvvo => new {
                tbcvvo.trips.Id,
                TripsFullNo = $"{tbcvvo.trips.TripsFullNo}   {tbcvvo.trips.TripsNo}",
                OperationTtype =
                    tbcvvo.trips.Loading
                        ? operationTtypes[tbcvvo.trips.OperationTtype ?? 0]
                        : $"{Language.ListOperateTransfer} {Language.ListEmpt}",
                Vehicl = $"{tbcvvo.vehicls.LicensePlate}/{tbcvvo.vehiclsType.ListItem}",
                CarrierEntities = tbcvvo.carriers.EntitieName,
                BeneficiaryEntities = tbcvvo.beneficiary!.EntitieName,
                Item = tbcvvo.items!.NoName,
                Driver = $"{tbcvvo.endrivers.DriverLicense}/{tbcvvo.endrivers.DriverName}"
            })
            .OrderByDescending(o=>o.Id);
```